# Infinite Square Well Normalization Issue

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, normalization

Let's say you have a well from $(0,a)$ and you want to find how some wave function changes with time. For our function we have:
$$\Psi(x,0)=Ax(x-a)$$
We can normalize this and everything is fine with bounds 0 to a. Now lets say we move the well to $(-a,a)$ and want to try to normalize a similar function and see how it changes with time. Let's take the function $$\Psi(x,0)=A(x-a)(x+a)$$But if we normalize this from $(-a,a)$ we find that the integral becomes $0$ and the function is un-normalizable. I don't understand why or if I am just making some dumb error.

Comment: Also, as far as I know, you now have a symmetrical well, taking 0 as the origin. So your solutions will be either even functions (using cos terms) or odd functions (using sin functions). Apologies if you know this already, or if I have misread your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral is not 0, for example - https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrat+(x-3)(x%2B3)+from+x%3D-3+to+x%3D3

also, you cn easily see your function does not change sign, so it's integral cannot be 0.